# Scheme: how to clear all the messages in a dialog

Tags: scheme, racket

i have a method that prints messages in a list on a dialog object. The code below is printing "a b c a b c d e" and i want it to be "a b c d e". How do i solve this problem? Is there a method that i can clear all the messages in a dialog object?

```
#lang racket/gui

(define frame (new frame%
                   [width 300]
                   [height 300]
                   [label "Frame"]))

(new button%
     [parent frame]
     [label "Messages"]
     (callback (lambda (button event)
                 (send msg-dialog show #t))))

(define msg-dialog (new dialog%
                         (label "Name")
                         (parent frame)
                         (width 300)
                         (height 300)))

(define (make-msg%)
  (new message% [parent msg-dialog]     
       [label "Message: "]
       [min-width 80]
       [min-height 30]))

(define (print-msg lst)
  (if (null? lst) 
      (void)
      (begin
        (send (make-msg%) set-label (symbol->string (car lst)))
        (print-msg (cdr lst)))))

(define list '(a b c))
(print-msg list)
(set! list (append list '(d e)))
(print-msg list)

(send frame show #t)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [GUIML](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/jphelps/guiml.plt/3/2/planet-docs/guiml/index.html) library has a function that can do it easily:

```
 (require (planet jphelps/guiml))
 (delete-children msg-dialog)
```

`delete-children` is implemented like this if you'd rather fork it:

```
(define (delete-children object (id #f))
  (send object change-children (λ (x)
                  (if id
                      (filter (λ (widget)
                         (not (eq? (send widget ___get-guiml-name) id)))
                          x)
                      '()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a text-field% instead.

```
http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text-field_.html?q=message%25
```

For a text field, the most useful methods of a `text%` object are the following:
`(send a-text get-text)` returns the current text of the editor.

`(send a-text erase)` deletes all text from the editor.

`(send a-text insert str)` inserts str into the editor at the current caret position.